# Configuring default loggingHandler in Spring Integration

Tags: logging, spring-integration

There is a custom handler on global errorChannel but it handles only specific errors, others are redirected to default loggingHandler.Is it possible to configure via xml default loggingHandler to output only error messages?

Answer (score 0):

The default logging handler **does** only log at ERROR level.

If you specify your own `errorChannel` bean (usually a pub/sub channel), the framework will not configure the default logging handler, so you can subscribe whatever handler(s) you want in that case.